# Copy and assignment constructor for arrays C++ example

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Need some help to write the copy and assignment constructors for my code. I get an error "an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list". Appreciate your help - thanks!

```
class B
{
public:
   C **table;
B() 
{
   table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE]();
}
B(const B& other)
{
   table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE](other.table);
   memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
}
B& operator = (const B& other)
{
  if (this == &other)
  {
    return *this;
  }
  delete[] table;
  table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE](other.table);
  memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
  return *this;
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's because of the way you're initializing `table`:

```
table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE](other.table);
memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
```

Try this insead:

```
table = new C *[TABLE_SIZE];
memcpy(table, other.table, sizeof(C *)* TABLE_SIZE);
```

I don't really understand why you would want to initialize the array's values, since that's what your `memcpy` is for anyway.